# access external Element Inside a for-each

Tags: xslt-1.0

I am having a problem trying to access elements outside of my for-each Loop.  Here is my XML.

```
<JobList sta.time="151.879">
<Job T.number="7" T.identifier="Tool" T.holder.comment="Holder" sta.time="30.789" />
<Job T.number="5" T.identifier="Second" T.holder.comment="secholder" sta.time="35.567" />
<Job T.number="7" T.identifier="Tool" T.holder.comment="Holder" sta.time="4.778" />
<Job T.number="5" T.identifier="Second" T.holder.comment="secholder" sta.time="80.745" />
<Tool sta.time="116.312" number="5" />
<Tool sta.time="35.567" number="7" />
</JobList>
```

Here is an extract of my XSL

```
<table width="100%" border="1">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>Numbers</td>
          <td>Description</td>
          <td>Holder</td>
          <td>Time</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <xsl:variable name="vsortOrder" select="//Job[@T.number]" />
        <xsl:for-each select="//Job[not(@T.number=preceding::Job/@T.number)]">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="@T.number" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="@T.identifier" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="@T.holder.comment" />
            </td>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:for-each select="//Tool[$vsortOrder/Job/@T.number]">
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="format-number(@sta.time div 60,'#0.00')" />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Desired Output:

```
     <div>
     <h1>
     <table width="100%" border="1">
     <thead>
        <tr>
           <td>Numbers</td>
           <td>Description</td>
           <td>Holder</td>
           <td>Time</td>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
        <tr>
           <td>7</td>
           <td>Tool</td>
           <td>Holder</td>
           <td>0.59</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>5</td>
           <td>Second</td>
           <td>secholder</td>
           <td>1.93</td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
  </table>
  </h1>
  </div>
```

I am trying to Display the value of "//Tool/sta.time" In the same order as @T.number.  Any Ideas how I would do this/structure this?

Comment: Probably a combination of overuse of `//`, too many `xsl:for-each`, and using `preceding::` instead of `preceding-sibling::`. Can you add your desired output so we can suggest some XSLT changes?

Comment: I added in the Desired result.

Comment: Your result does not make sense: the `sta.time` value linked to `T.number = 7` is 35.567, which after division by 60 produces 0.59. Yet you show 0.59 in the row where T.number = 5. And where did the value of 0.84 come from?

Comment: I didnt update the Desired result when I updated the XML.  its updated now correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***--- edited in view of clarifications ---***

The preferred way to select the `Tool` whose `number` matches the `T.number` of the current `Job` is to define a **[key](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#key)** as:

```
<xsl:key name="tool" match="Tool" use="@number" />
```

and then use it as:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(key('tool', @T.number)/@sta.time div 60,'0.00')"/>
```

---

Note also that this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//Job[not(@T.number=preceding::Job/@T.number)]">
```

is not a good way to eliminate duplicates. You should be using the [Muenchian method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) instead, as shown in the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="job" match="Job" use="@T.number" />
<xsl:key name="tool" match="Tool" use="@number" />

<xsl:template match="/JobList">
    <table width="100%" border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Numbers</td>
                <td>Description</td>
                <td>Holder</td>
                <td>Time</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <xsl:for-each select="Job[count(. | key('job', @T.number)[1]) = 1]">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="@T.number" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="@T.identifier" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="@T.holder.comment" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(key('tool', @T.number)/@sta.time div 60,'0.00')"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this is applied to your input example, the result will be:

```
<table width="100%" border="1">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <td>Numbers</td>
         <td>Description</td>
         <td>Holder</td>
         <td>Time</td>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>7</td>
         <td>Tool</td>
         <td>Holder</td>
         <td>0.59</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>5</td>
         <td>Second</td>
         <td>secholder</td>
         <td>1.94</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

This is different from the result shown in your question - but I suspect it is the correct result nevertheless.

Comment: I have tryed out your second XSL Code and it works but I came across one Issue with it.  I forgot to mention in my question that the "Tool" elements is in numerical order by T.number.  So when I run your code, Its not printing out the sta.time in the correct order and some areas have a NaN in it.  I have updated the code in the question.

Comment: @AlexW Would it be correct to assume that `Job` and `Tool `are linked by a common value in `T.number` and  `number`? And if yes, are any of these unique? Please update your example and show any duplicates that may occur.

Comment: Yes "T.number" is the same as "number" but "T.number" is Sorted in the Order I need it to be displayed which is why I was using it.   I updated the XML with duplicates with the proper "sta.time" values also I really appreciate you helping me out

Comment: This Worked Perfect Thank you for you help.  I have been learning lots from everyone on Stack overflow and you, how code can be manipulated and how certain functions work.  Thank you again  This has just made my day.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the positions of your job elements and Tool elements to map the `Job` to `Tool`. Since first occurrence of Job corresponds to first occurrence of Tool element in the source XML, do something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <table width="100%" border="1">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>Numbers</td>
          <td>Description</td>
          <td>Holder</td>
          <td>Time</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <xsl:variable name="vsortOrder" select="//Tool" />
        <xsl:for-each select="//Job[not(@T.number=preceding::Job/@T.number)]">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="@T.number" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="@T.identifier" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="@T.holder.comment" />
            </td>
            <td>
            <xsl:variable name="job-position" select="position()"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number($vsortOrder[position()=$job-position]/@sta.time div 60,'0.00')"/>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Form the test `<xsl:for-each select="//Job[not(@T.number=preceding::Job/@T.number)]">`, it seems you may have two (or more?) Job elements with the same T.number and you want to treat them as one. For that, I would suggest using muenchian grouping to save jobs with unique T.number and then match their positions with the position of Tool elements present in `vsortOrder`.

Comment: **1.** You cannot use `exsl:node-set()` without binding the `exsl` prefix to its namespace first. -- **2.** There is no need to use `exsl:node-set()` here; the variable is already a node-set. And neither is there a real need for the variable.

Comment: Thanks @michael.hor257k. I have removed the node-set extension function. I am sticking with using the variable as it's part of my original solution.

Comment: I forgot to mention in my question that the "Tool" elements is in numerical order by T.number.  I updated the question with the new values.  When I tryed out your code,  sta.time wasnt in the right order.  Sorry for not imputing that in my question.  I overlooked it.